# Extract row from Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

My dataframe look like this:

```
Month       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec  
Year                                                     
2015  -0.087763 -0.044687  0.074335 -0.047496  0.009380  
2016  -0.016767  0.017330 -0.019376  0.032446 -0.008402  
2017  -0.015696 -0.017499  0.047880  0.017623 -0.008918  
2018  -0.032041  0.013559 -0.073149  0.032732 -0.015669  
2019  -0.058844  0.004336  0.035221 -0.011134  0.009052  
mean  -0.030830 -0.010107  0.009877  0.013574  0.021104
```

I like to extract the last row("mean") so I can put inside a list.

I tried the following:

```
a = df_final.tail(1).values.tolist()
```

---> result below:

```
[[0.009656344803844981, 
  0.009396282528774218, 
  0.007030633691263447, 
  0.02658556550533946, 
  -0.007079112777794713, 
  0.0016991287767502451, 
  0.014585248218691213, 
  -0.03082982444347945, 
  -0.010107077716506988, 
  0.009877350168478648, 
  0.013574204095420709, 
  0.02110427999089128]]
```

How do I remove the extra brackets so I can use this list to insert into another dataframe?

Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `df.tail(1).values.flatten().tolist()` or `df.tail(1).values[0].tolist()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`a[0]` should return what you want